# Hibernate : Update Associated Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring, extjs, annotations

The following question is related with these technologies:

- Hibernate 4 or 3
- Spring 3.1
- Jackson
- Ext JS 4

Suppose that I have two tables, say parent and child.

The parent class is as follows:

```
class Parent {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

The child class is as follows:

```
class Child {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne // uni-directional many-to-one association to Parent
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Now, there are already these data on the database:

Table: parent

```
 id   name
===================
 1    parent one
 2    parent two
```

Table: child

```
 id   name         parent_id
=============================
 1    child one    2
```

**The question is**: Can I update the parent of "child one" from "parent two" to "parent one"
by using these objects:

```
Parent newParent = new Parent();
newParent.setId(1);

Child child = new Child();
child.setId(1);
child.setParent(newParent);

session.saveOrUpdate(child);
```

**For additional information**, the child object is auto mapped by Spring MVC+Jackson from JSON which is sent from browser by ExtJS.

The JSON format is as follows:

```
{id: 1, name: "child one", parent: {id: 1, name: "parent one"}}
```

So, the child and newParent objects above is actually created and set **implicitly** by Spring MVC+Jackson.

So the actual code inside Spring MVC controller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "child/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> update(@RequestBody Child child) {

    // validation for child object

    session.saveOrUpdate(child)

    // prepare response
}
```

**Also important here**, the JSON sent from browser may be contains the name of new parent

```
... parent: {id: 1, name: "parent one"} ...
```

Although those "name" property might also be mapped by Spring, it should be ommitted by Hibernate, because I just want to update "child one" record, not update the name (of "parent one" record).

I know that it can be done easily by using HQL. But because the browser sends JSON, and Spring can map the JSON to object automatically, so it would be easier to use session.saveOrUpdate() instead of HQL.

Any suggestion how to do all these ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I update the parent of "child one" from "parent two" to "parent one" by using these objects?

Short answer: yes.

The browser sends JSON to the server; Spring receives the request and maps it to `update()`; Spring examines the `Content-Type` header and determines that the response body contains `application/json`; Spring checks in its `messageConverters` to see if you have any converter which can handle JSON; Spring finds Jackson and converts the JSON into your `Child` object; this object is passed in to `update()` where you can do operations on it, for example, saving it with hibernate via `saveOrUpdate()`.

As long as the `parent` field is the owning side of the relationship (and it is, from the model you've given), the relationship between "child one" and its parents will be updated. The name provided for the parent **might** be committed; this depends upon your cascading rules.

What happens internally is that Jackson creates new `Parent` and `Child` objects and hibernate finds the existing entities based on the IDs; the parent ID already exists, so `saveOrUpdate()` chooses an update.

Comment: Thank you berbajay. But if I update the same record twice, I got this exception: _org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session_

Comment: In this case you need to use [merge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge(java.lang.Object)) to harmonize your object with the Session.